# CORS blocked while Upload large file to Windows Azure Blob Storage failed

Tags: javascript, file-upload, cors, azure-blob-storage, azure-mobile-services

I am stuck with the uploading of large blobs to Windows Azure Blob Storage.

I followed this [link](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/) and, locally, everything goes fine.

Then I loaded my website, fully coded in HTML5 + JS, and the file upload feature does not work anymore. When I try to upload the first chunk, the browser stops the request because of CORS.

I followed this [link](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/), hoping to solve the issue, and the CORS rule in Windows Azure Blob Storage now says::

```
Allowed origins: *
Allowed methods: Get, Put
Allowed headers: *
Exposed headers: x-ms-*
Max age (seconds): 3600
```

So i think that every request, from any origin, to my BlobService should not be rejected due to the CORS. Am I wrong?

To describe my setup:

- I have a Windows Azure Mobile Service which generates a SAS for me. I wonder why the SAS baseUrl is an http instead of https.
- I have a website, protected by a certificate, that runs using the https protocol. Everything goes on https.
- The website queries the service and it successfully gets a valid SAS.
- If I use the SAS as is, with the url with the http protocol, the browser blocks the request because it is an "Active Mixed Content" (an http request issued by a https web site).
- If I change the SAS url, forcing it to use the https protocol, the browser blocks the request because of the CORS.
- My Azure Mobile Service Back-end is in NodeJS and I have not found a way to let it create an https SAS.

The code which upload a chunk of a file is the following (JS):

```
function uploadSlicedChunk(data){
    //Block id padding
    var num = '' + UploadManager.blockIdCounter;
    while(num.length < 10){
        num = '0'+num; 
    }
    var blockId = btoa("block-"+num);

    //URI and data creation
    var uri = UploadManager.submitUri.substr(0,4)+"s"+UploadManager.submitUri.substr(4, UploadManager.submitUri.length)+"&comp=block&blockId="+blockId;
    var requestData = new Uint8Array(data);

    //AJAX options
    var ajaxOption = {
        url : uri,
  type : "PUT",
  data : requestData,
  processData : false,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', requestData.length);
        },
  success : function (data, status) {
      //Upoad successfull -> update tracking variables.
            UploadManager.blockIds.push(blockId);
      UploadManager.blockIdCounter += 1;
      UploadManager.bytesSent += requestData.length;
      UploadManager.currentFilePointer += UploadManager.maxBlockSize;
      UploadManager.totalRemainingBytes -= UploadManager.maxBlockSize;
      if(UploadManager.totalRemainingBytes < UploadManager.maxBlockSize){
          UploadManager.maxBlockSize = UploadManager.totalRemainingBytes;
      }

      //Prepare next upload;                    
      var percentComplete = ((parseFloat(UploadManager.bytesSent) / parseFloat(UploadManager.fileLen)) * 100).toFixed(2);
            $("#content-saving-logger").append(percentComplete + " %<br />");
            if(UploadManager.totalRemainingBytes > 0){
                var fileContent = UploadManager.file.slice(UploadManager.currentFilePointer, 
                    UploadManager.currentFilePointer+UploadManager.maxBlockSize);
                UploadManager.reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);
            } else {
                UploadManager.commitBlob();
            }
        },
  error : function(jqXHR, status, error){
      alert(status + ", "+error+": "+jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    };
    $.ajax(ajaxOption);
}
```

I do not know what to do now to solve the issue... The only solution I found is to prepare a service on my Azure Mobile Services which receives the chunks and uploads them to the Blob Storage, making it a sort of proxy. And, at the end of the process, it commits the blob. But, basically, it will makes the service slower and it requires a lot of more work... while this solution should work!

Thank you for your patience and for your help,
    Ric.

Comment: You probably have to set the `xhr.withCredentials = true` flag

Comment: I have to add it in the `beforeSend` function?

Comment: Nope... also with that flag set to true, the request is blocked by the browser due to CORS...